# Having Trouble Running A Custom Query In Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mariadb

OK I've been staring at this for hours and I can't see anything wrong.  I'm hoping one of you super bright people can see my mistake.  I have copied the select statement and and run it on PHPMYAdmin and it runs ok there but it returns no results in Wordpress.  I have also verified that the 2 variables are populated correctly.

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$terms = wp_get_object_terms($user->ID, 'departments');
$term = $terms[0]->term_id;

$results = $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT post_title, post_content
        FROM wp_posts
        INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id
        INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.id = wp_term_relationships.object_id
        WHERE post_type = 'events'
        AND meta_key = 'event_date'
        AND meta_value = %s
        AND term_taxonomy_id = %s"),array($date,$term));
```

If I do a var_dump of $results I just get NULL.

Comment: is the query returning values when run on db directly?

Comment: I miss the execute statement, ->prepare, ->execute, ->get_result

Comment: @LelioFaieta yes when I run the query directly it returns the expected results.

Comment: @Grumpy $wpdb->get_results() automatically executes the query.https://docs.w3cub.com/wordpress/classes/wpdb/get_results

Comment: @RickJames I don't see how this applies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in your prepare statement... `array($date,$term)` needs to be inside the prepare function.

**Example**

```
// Bad- args outside of prepare
$results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($sql), $args);

// Good- args inside prepare
$results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($sql, $args));
```

**Relevant Docs**

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/

**Solution for Your Code**

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$terms = wp_get_object_terms($user->ID, 'departments');
$term = $terms[0]->term_id;
$results = $wpdb->get_results(
  $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT post_title, post_content
    FROM wp_posts
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id
    INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.id = wp_term_relationships.object_id
    WHERE post_type = 'events'
    AND meta_key = 'event_date'
    AND meta_value = %s
    AND term_taxonomy_id = %s",
    array($date,$term)
));
```

Comment: thank you so much.  I knew it would be something silly I was missing I just couldn't see it

Comment: Great happy to help!